# Playframework 2.5.4. Cannot connect to database [db] (MySql)

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have created new play-scala app and I can't connect to mysql db.

 Erorr: 
Configuration error 
Cannot connect to database [db] 
c.z.h.HikariConfig - either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required, more details [here](https://gist.github.com/mkovacek/a6634625bf3143680200cd0975e1dd65)

To the same db with the same config I can connect with play 2.2.3

[build.sbt](https://gist.github.com/mkovacek/9ca2e0d0c1dabecb95d5259fc1366307) 

[application.conf](https://gist.github.com/mkovacek/5c99b2005d93a00fe3166172ad53481d)

Comment: You can first have a look at the updated documentation: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: Is your mysqld daemon running? Are you connecting with the correct url?

Comment: @Mika'il yes is running. url is correct because with old play 2.2.3. app I can connect

Comment: @cchantep I have done everything how it says in docs. In sbt I have jdbc and mysql dependency, in config connection props

Comment: could you drop a piece of code where you try to access the DB in your controller or service? That will help us to see what is not ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `db.db.default.*` instead of `db.default.*`.

**In your config**:

```
db {
  db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sc_cvs"
  # (...)
}
```

**Correct**:

```
db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sc_cvs"
  # (...)
}
```